# Training LSTM Model in Torch and Data Structure

Tags: torch, lstm

I am new to Torch and I am trying to implement LSTM.  Below is the code that I have.  Is this the correct way to implement an LSTM using the rnn library or is there more I need to do?

Also, what should my data look like for inputting into an LSTM? Just ordered with 2 inputs and 1 output?

```
require 'rnn'
require 'nn'

-- Build Model
lm = nn.Sequential()
rnn = nn.Sequencer(nn.FastLSTM(2, 30)) 
lm:add(rnn)
lm:add(nn.Linear(30, 1))

-- Train Model on 'data'
criterion = nn.MSECriterion()  
trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(lm, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.01
trainer:train(data)
```

Comment: Check out this very good tutorial here: https://apaszke.github.io/lstm-explained.html